# Confinement of atoms and molecules

Tags: molpro

I have started working on Molpro for casscf calculations on molecules. I need to calculate properties of the molecules say HCl under confinement by various spherical potentials. How can I impose Dirichlet boundary condition at a finite radius? Can I use Molpro package for this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: +1 but which property, which potential, and what precisley is being fixed by the Dirichlet boundary condition?

Comment: Wave function must vanish at a finite confining radius of hard wall potential and calculate potential energy curves of ground and excited states of HCl

Comment: Which wavefunction? The electronic wavefunction in HCl?

Comment: Is [this](https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xcontrol.html#confining-in-a-cavity) what you are looking for?